# Unable to Execute Python Code from Custom Shell Function in Git Bash

Tags: python, bash, git, configuration, git-bash

I am trying to create a custom shell function in Git Bash that allows me to execute a specific Python code snippet when typing a certain command, such as "Tree". However, I'm encountering an issue where the code is not executing as expected and I receive the following error message:

```
$ Tree
$ bash: command not found
```

Here are the details:

I have created a custom shell function in my Git Bash configuration file `~/.bash_profile` as follows:

```
tree() {
    python -c '
from directory_tree import display_tree
display_tree()
'
}
```

he display_tree() function is defined in a separate Python file called directory_tree.py, which is located in a directory accessible by the Python interpreter. The function is responsible for displaying the directory tree structure.

The expected behavior is that when I type Tree in any directory within Git Bash, it should execute the Python code and display the directory tree structure. However, when I try to run the command, I receive the $ Tree: bash: command not found error.

I have already ensured that the directory_tree.py file is located in the correct directory and that the Python interpreter can import the display_tree function successfully.

Am I missing something in my shell function definition or in the way I'm executing the Python code? How can I troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!